# jspm and highmaps, how to import?

Tags: highcharts, angular, jspm, highmaps

Trying to import highmaps and jspm, 2 days and no luck.

```
import * as Ng2Highcharts from 'highcharts/modules/map';
Ng2Highcharts(Highcharts);
```

but getting an error that Ng2Highcharts is an object, which it is, but I dont know to which method inside Ng2Highcharts do I need to pass Highcharts to???

you can checkout my config.js here:
https://github.com/born2net/studioDashboard/blob/hot-reload/jspm.config.js

and my entire class here:
https://github.com/born2net/studioDashboard/blob/hot-reload/src/comps/app1/dashboard/StationsMap.ts

here is debug snap:

[image]

any help is GREATLY appreciated,

Sean